# Plasma Task Manager won't display windows on current screen (dual head)

Tags: arch-linux, plasma, panel

I have a dual screen setup on my `Arch` box with Plasma 5.19.5 and have realized that on my second screen, the task manager setting "Show only tasks: From current screen" doesn't seem to work correctly. When I activate it, all tasks are hidden from the panel on this screen  - even the ones currently located on this one. What's wrong?
My settings:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm having an identical problem with Mageia Linux and 5.15.4 of plasma, causes task manager icons to vanish, even when I can see the window on the screen.

I haven't confirmed this properly this but it seems to happen after my laptop has been woken after the screen has gone off, it seems that minimised windows on the external monitor while the screen is off are "orphaned" and will no longer associate themselves with either monitor. The only way to get them back is to turn off the filter, close and re-start the application. They will then behave normally with the filter again until the next time the screen blanks.

Answer (score 0):

The same happens for me. Only partial solution I found is to remove and add the task manager from the panel. Slightly less inconvenient than restarting all apps.

Comment: Try plasma 5.20.0

Answer (score 0):

I ultimately ended up upgrading to Plasma 5.20.0 and the problem went away.